# Term for a graph respecting homotopy class

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, homotopy-theory

Is there a term for a graph on a manifold $M$ whose edges respect homotopy?

For example, define an "edge" on $M$ to be a continuous path $f : [0,1] \rightarrow M$. I would consider two different edges to be equivalent iff they share the same endpoints, and are homotopic.

Comment: I don't know, but I think it's reasonable to simply call it a graph.

Comment: The graph you describe in your question (when accompanied by the operation of concatenation) has a name, it is called the fundamental groupoid of $M$.